# one problem in fetching a data from backend in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, fetch

i have two item in form it is---1 is textbox and 2nd is combo box.
now i have single value in textbox .
but there is a multiple value for a combobox with is totally depend on a value of textbox....

**i am already add data to the backend files ... in which 1 columns that is called column A it's value is for textbox  and 2 column that is called column B it's value for combo box **

When i write in textbox it's dependent ALL value can be get in the combo box.
Can any one solve my problem... It is a row vice search.....

I used a Ms Access for my backend......
How i can create a table that can be i used for a my problem

Give me any reference or codes.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by " When i write in textbox it's dependent ALL value can be get in the combo box." Please clarify.

Comment: Please post one or two examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably Category->Product kind of scenario, where ONE Category can have ONE or MORE Products,

Category "Softdrink" can have Products("Coke","Pepsi" etc.)

Category "Harddrink" can have Products("8 PM","BP",etc.)

So when u will put "Softdrink" in your textbox then you want to get the relevant products for it. (Assumed you are using TextChange event)

SQL - select Product.Name from Category Inner Join Product On Category.Id= Product.Category_Id where CategoryName ="Softdrink"

and table structure would be like,
[image]